# How to achieve sharp subtitle appearance in WMP - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, subtitles, media-player-classic

I use WMP and MPC-HC in my Windows7 PC. Everything is fine with MPC-HC, and I installed Shark 007 codecs for WMP.

In Shark codec setting I selected **FFDShow DXVA** for subtitles. It works well, I have configured WMP to use subtitles when available. The problem is with the font. From WMP->Options->DVD->Advanced , I can access the FFDShow subtitle options.

[image: FFDShow Settings]

Subtitles appear fine When window is not maximized/fullscreen. When window is enlarged, the font enlarges (as it should be), but becomes blurry, and looks bad. Below are the screenshots of subtitles when window is normal and then maximized.

This [image: Normal] changes to [image].

But in MPC-HC, the font becomes enlarged when window maximizes, but still, the font looks good, sharp and smooth. Below are the screenshots of subtitles when window is normal and then maximized.

[image: MPC-HC normal font] -> [image: MPC-HC maximized font].

The MPC-HC subtitle settings are;

[image: MPC-HC Subs settings]

How can I achieve good quality subtitle appearance as in mpc hc in my **WMP**? I want these good quality subtitles to appear in my **Windows Media Player** too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using [DirectVobSub](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/directvobsub.htm) instead of FFDShow for displaying subtitles? Subtitle support in MPC-HC is based on DirectVobSub.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution to this problem:

Go to `Options -> Subtitle -> Maximum texture resolution`

Change to `Desktop` and your subtitles should look good.

Comment: where are these settings to be applied? can you post a screenshot of the settings window, coz it will be very useful.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/D0AuUYx.png

Comment: I want high quality subtitles in my **Windows Media Player** and not **MPC-HC**